# Perl: Repair utf8 xml file which contains octal or hexadecimal codes

Tags: xml, perl, encoding

I got from a Linux-server an xml-file on a window10-machine. The file was base64-coded. I decoded the xml with a Perl-script using function `decode_base64`from `MIME::Base64`. I tested with a Perl-script if it is well-formed but this was not the case:

```
C:\test>perl test_well_formed.pl test.xml
test.xml:3: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xFC 0x6C 0x6C 0x65
<print>M³ller</print>
        ^
```

I looked at the content. Notepad++ displays the umlaut ü as hexadecimal code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
<print>MxFCller</print>
</test>
```

and Emacs displays ü as octal code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
<print>M\374ller</print>
</test>
```

The encoding in Emacs was:

```
 Its value is ‘utf-8-dos’
```

Obviously, the hexadecimal and octal-codes are not allowed in utf8 xml.

What I want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>
<print>Müller</print>
</test>
```

My main question is: How can I repair the xml-files?

One solution could be to read with a Perl-script line by line or *slurp* and replace the hexadecimal code (or octal code?) with the umlaut. Or is there a better way to repair? For example, could umlaute considered when the base64-file is converted?

A second question is: Why does one editor displays octal codes and the other hexadecimal codes?

Here are the screenshots of notepad++ and Emacs:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post text (only) as images. I now have to retype one of them :(

Comment: @Ikegami I did the retyping. I used screenshots on purpose to show that these are not only characters but codes which ar highlighed by the editors.

Comment: Right, which is why I didn't say not to use images of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have "hex codes" or "octal codes". That's how Notepad++ and Emacs display invalid bytes in the file.

The problem is that this doesn't match the file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

As the message says, you need to specify the correct encoding. For example, if the file is encoded using Windows-1252, you should be using

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
```

Another way of making them match, and probably the one that makes the most sense, is to convert the file to use UTF-8.

Inside a Perl script, the following could be used:

```perl
use Encode qw( from_to );

from_to( $xml, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8" )
```

From the command line, this could be done using `iconv`.

```sh
iconv -f Windows-1252 -t UTF-8
```

---

> *Why does one editor displays octal codes and the oder hexadecimal codes?*

First of all, it's not a different number.

And because hex was the preferred representation of bytes when Notepad++ was written, octal having been abandoned long before.

Comment: Both editors says that the file is already encoded utf8 (`Emacs:  Its value is ‘utf-8-dos’`)

Comment: You saved my live. I used the conversion (`form_to`) and it works. But I'm still confused why the editors displays utf8.

Comment: Re "*Both editors says that the file is already encoded utf8*", Yes, and yet they don't see the "ü". So they're wrong. It's not their fault, though. The file claims it's encoded using UTF-8, but it's not so. And that's the problem.